# Can't delete row from a database

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm working at some school project and my job here is to make a delete button for that list view in Java FX, but the problem is that when i want to proceed that it shows me this error. I tried some solutions, but none of them worked.

so here's the code

```
@FXML
private void removeStudentOnClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException{
    ModelEditStudent student=(ModelEditStudent)tables.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String sql="DELETE FROM student WHERE nr_indeksu=?";

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Usuwanie studenta");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Czy na pewno chcesz usunąc tego studenta z listy?");
    Optional <ButtonType> action = alert.showAndWait();

    if(action.get() == ButtonType.OK){

    tables.getItems().removeAll(tables.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());  

    try{

        try (Connection myConn = ConnectionManager.getConnection()) {
         try (PreparedStatement st = myConn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            st.setString(1, student.getNr_indeksu());
            st.executeUpdate();
        }
        myConn.close();

    }

    }catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

and there's the error:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
 (`wu`.`oceny`, CONSTRAINT `oceny_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`nr_indeksu`)
 REFERENCES `student` (`nr_indeksu`))
```

All the point of this operation is about selecting the row and removing from the database after pressing a button. By now it works only for the listview, but it doesn't remove records from the database.

Anyone got an idea how make it work?

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Make sure id is proper when passing in the parameter and you can use try multicache. It makes code clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your DB schema. try fixing the foreign keys dependencies.I mean the value of nr_indeksu exists in another table of your DB.

Comment: Yes, i changed it in the easiest way just adding other tables using nr_indeksu to my DELETE statement. but there's still some syntax error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE nr_indeksu = '964634'' at line 1
 Call me stupid, but i really dont know where the syntax error is.

Comment: Are you expecting us to tell you where the syntax error is, when you haven't shown us the new SQL statement?

Comment: String sql="DELETE FROM student, wniosek, oceny, przedmioty WHERE nr_indeksu = ? ";

Comment: No, you'll need to have four separate SQL statements - one for each table.  And you'll need the delete from `student` to be run last.

Answer (score 0):

You have a table called `oceny` which has a column `nr_indeksu` that contains student ids.  You have created a foreign key constraint on that table, which requires those student ids to match up with something in the `student` table.

If you try to delete something in the `student` table that's referenced by the `oceny` table, you will get this error, because otherwise, it would leave the database in a state where the `oceny` table references a student that doesn't exist.

There are a number of solutions to this.  You will need to think about what should actually happen in this case - what do you want to have happen to the `oceny` rows when you delete a matching student.

One option would be for you to change the foreign key to make it do a "cascade delete" - that is, the `oceny` automatically gets deleted in the same transaction as the `student`.  There's [some information here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) on how to do that.

Comment: Ok, i changed it and now it looks like this  

  String sql="DELETE FROM student, wniosek, oceny, przedmioty WHERE nr_indeksu = ? ";

But, there's still an error like this 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE nr_indeksu = '964634'' at line 1

call me stupid, but i really can't see where the syntax error is